# Oracle Apex Ajax call returned server error ORA-01722: invalid number for ajax_dispatch_request

Tags: oracle-apex

Apologies first for not being able to replicate this issue but i'll try to expain.

In my Interactive grid, i have columns and the download to excel was working fine which is default in IG.

Recently i am facing the error: Ajax call returned server error ORA-01722: invalid number for ajax_dispatch_request

Before this i had added an atatchments column but i even tried to exclude it from print/export. Still i am getting this error.

What could be the possible reasons for this type of error?

Oracle Apex- 22.1

Edit: Upon full debug i get this part in stacktrace:

ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC",~

Does it mean tilde operator somewhere is creating problem?